# Programs counting even and odd numbers

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm self-studying C and I'm trying to make 2 programs for exercise:

1. the first one takes a number and check if it is even or odd;
   This is what I came up with for the first one:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(){
         int n;
         printf("Enter a number that you want to check: ");
         scanf("%d",&n);
         if((n%2)==0)      
              printf("%d is even.",n);
         else
              printf("%d is odd.",n);
         return 0;
   }
   ```
2. the second one should take *n* numbers as input and count the number of even numbers, odd numbers, and zeros among the numbers that were entered. The output should be the number of  even numbers, odd numbers, and zeros.

I would like to ask how to implement the loop in this case: how can I set an EOF value if every integer is acceptable (and so I cannot, say, put 0 to end)? Can you show me how to efficiently build this short code?

Comment: Do you want to accept any N or can the user enter the N before entering all the numbers?

Comment: @REACHUS what do you mean?

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()` for `EOF`.

Comment: In your first example your are accepting user input.  @chux & @REACHUS are saying you need to specify how the input will be received.  Will the user type in a comma delimited string?  Or, will this just be a function that accepts parameters of `int[] data, int size`?

Comment: @bigtlb I see what you mean. The user should add the numbers one after another and eventually ender an EOF character (but which one, since all numbers are acceptable?) to stop entering numbers and getting the result.

Comment: `EOF` is not the usual user input.  A special key sequence (example Crtl-D) signals to `stdin` that no more input will occur.  `scanf()` detects that condition and does not assign anything to `n`.  The result of `scanf()` let's code know what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n, nEven=0, nOdd=0, nZero=0;

    for (;;) {
        printf("\nEnter a number that you want to check: ");
        //Pressing any non-numeric character will break;
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) break;

        if (n == 0) {
            nZero++;
        }
        else {
            if (n % 2) {
                nEven++;
            }
            else {
                nOdd++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("There were %d even, %d odd, and %d zero values.", nEven, nOdd, nZero);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But how can I draw the flowchart of this so that it is structured?

Comment: This sounds like a different question.  But if I had to draw a flowchart of this, I guess it would look like what I added above.

Comment: I see. Thanks. By the way, which software did you use to make the flowchart?

Comment: I think he probably used diagrams.net

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `scanf()`

1, 1 field was filled (n).
0, 0 fields filled, likely somehtlig like "abc" was entered for a number.
EOF, End-of-file encountered (or rarely IO error).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int n;

  for (;;) {  
    printf("Enter a number that you want to check: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) break;
    if((n%2)==0)      
      printf("%d is even.",n);
    else
      printf("%d is odd.",n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or read the count of numbers to subsequently read:

```
int main(void) {
  int n;

  printf("Enter the count of numbers that you want to check: ");
  if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) Handle_Error();

  while (n > 0) {  
    n--;
    printf("Enter a number that you want to check: ");
    int i;
    if (scanf("%d",&i) != 1) break;
    if((i%2)==0) {
      if (i == 0) printf("%d is zero.\n",i);
      else printf("%d is even and not 0.\n",i);
    }
    else
      printf("%d is odd.\n",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(;;)` simple means loop forever.  The later `if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) break;` breaks out of the loop.  The answers demonstrate that code can either loop until `EOF` is detected, or loop `n` times as in the second case.  The odd/even/zero detail is still left for you to code.

Comment: @user62029 `scanf()` returns a count of successful conversions (or EOF).  `scanf("%d",&i)` returns `1` when a successful scan of an `int` occurs. If the input was non-numeric like "abc",  `scanf("%d",&i)` returns 0 (and the "abc" is still in `stdin`).  If there is no more input (the EOF condition occurred), `EOF` is returned.  We only want to continue looping if 1 is returned.  So when the result is `!= 1`, code breaks or jumps to just after the `for/while` loop.

Comment: @user62029 Note: `EOF` is _not_ a valued saved in `n`.  It is a value returned from `scanf()` indicating there is no more input available.  It that case, `n` is not assigned a new value.

Comment: @user62029 You will have a _different_ structured flowchart.  Many approaches exist. Consider answers from SO as samples, and not _the_ way to code.

Answer (score -1):

hey look at this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()

{    

       int nodd,neven,num,digit ; 
       clrscr();



       printf("Count number of odd and even digits in a given integer number ");

       scanf("%d",&num);

                nodd = neven =0; /* count of odd and even digits */

                while (num> 0)

                    {

                        digit = num % 10; /* separate LS digit from number */

                        if (digit % 2 == 1)

                           nodd++;

                        else neven++;

                               num /= 10; /* remove LS digit from num */

                    }

                        printf("Odd digits : %d Even digits: %d\n", nodd, neven);

                        getch();

}
```

Comment: That doesn't even compile.  What's `clrscr()`?  It's certainly not something defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Toby clrscr() is - I believe - from the old Borland C compilers. It clears the screen (like many other functions like gotoxy(), textbackground() etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,evenN=0,oddN=0,zeros=0;
    char key;
    do{
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter a number that you want to check: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==0){
            printf("%d is zero.",n);
            zeros++;
        }
        else if((n%2)==0){      
            printf("%d is even.",n);
            evenN++; 
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is odd.",n);
            oddN++;
        }
        puts("Press ENTER to enter another number. ESC to exit");
        do{
        key = getch();
        }while(key!=13 || key!=27) //13 is the ascii code fore enter key, and 27 is for escape key

    }while(key!=27) 
    clrscr();
    printf("Total even numbers: %d",evenN);
    printf("Total odd numbers: %d",oddN);
    printf("Total odd numbers: %d",zeros);
    return 0;
}
```

This program ask for a number, evaluate the number and then ask to continue for another number or exit.